# Make image fade out on mouseover in the div

Tags: css, html, hover

I know my question may look weird at first, but let me explain...

I have a div, named subcontainer which contains two elements :
Two icons and a link.

Basically, I want the div to make the two icons disappear on hover, BUT not my link. Here is my code :

```
<div class="subcontainer">
<img class="icons" src="images/arrow_right.png"/>
<a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">Follow me</a>
<img class="icons" src="images/arrow_left.png"/>
</div>
```

**Edit : I want the icons to disappear on subcontainer:hover. Not on icons:hover.

If you have any questions to help me, just ask! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use psuedo selectors:

#### View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/hajt6/3/

By doing it this way, you are telling it to only target the `img` elements that are children of the `.subcontainer`, but also allowing you to target the entire `div` without affecting the `a` element.

```
<div class="subcontainer">
<img class="icons" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ose/Arrow%20Right.png"/>
<a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">Follow me</a>
<img class="icons" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ose/Arrow%20Right.png"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.subcontainer:hover > img {
    transition: 0.2s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume that's what you meant? ;-)

Comment: It's surprising how uncommon this sort of thing is. Learn your CSS3 and avoid JS if you can. jQuery is super powerful, but a tad bloated. Any CSS solution is always better :-)

Comment: Never really tried JS. I'm really a beginner in the web programming world and CSS3 looks way more simple! Thank you again.

Comment: If you need more control, you could have used `.icons` instead of `img`. Just a tip in case you need it later ;-) Thanks for the vote.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the image fade, use the following CSS:

```
.icons{
    transition: all 0.5s; /*how long you want the fade to last*/
}

.icons:hover{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74wPn/

EDIT: Revised to fit asker's comment's needs.

```
.icons{
    transition: all 0.5s; /*how long you want the fade to last*/
}

.subcontainer:hover .icons{
    opacity:0
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74wPn/1/

Comment: I tried this option, but it's not what I want. I want the icons to disappear on mouseover ANYWHERE in the subcontainer div. So when I put my cursor on the div, it calls an action or whatever to hide the icons.

Comment: Thank you! Your way worked as well as Nicolas' one (which I used). :)

Comment: I like this solution, but switching the hover and transition state to the parent container `.subcontainer:hover img{}` will make it work as requested in the op.

Answer (score 1):

Do this way:

```
.icons:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to disappear instantly:

```
.icons:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want it to do it over a set time period:

```
.icons:hover {
    transition: 0.2s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.

```
$(".icons").hover(function(){
$(".icons").hide();
});
```